# Two points through the vertical meridian line

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polyline

We have a problem with drawing marker on Polyline which goes through the vertical meridian line (I selected the line in red).

Image for your reference
[image]

It all works when the marker does not go over this line.

Code:

```
<div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```

```
function initialize() {

var path = [
    {"lat":8.35750896119,"lng":-83.91185135579997},
    {"lat":49.93177613,"lng":155.39886474599996},
    {"lat":35.93177613,"lng":130.39886474599996}
];
    var offset = 1;

var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
  map: map
});

var position = getLatLngForDistanceOnPolyline(line, offset);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
});
map.setCenter(position);

 var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    var newPosition = getLatLngForDistanceOnPolyline(line, offset);
    marker.setPosition(newPosition);
    offset++;
    if(offset > 100) offset = 1;
 }, 50);}
function getLatLngForDistanceOnPolyline(polyline, offset){
var dist = 0;
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyline.getPath(), 0);
var offsetDistance = distance * offset / 100.00;

var points = polyline.getPath().getArray();

if(points.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++){
        var pointStart  = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat(), points[i].lng());
        var pointEnd    = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i + 1].lat(), points[i + 1].lng());
        var curDistance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pointStart, pointEnd);
        var prevDist = dist;
        dist += curDistance;

        if(offsetDistance <= dist) {
            var diff = offsetDistance - prevDist;
            diff = diff / curDistance;
            var d = diff / (1.0 - diff);

            return new google.maps.LatLng(
                ( points[i].lat() + ( d * points[i + 1].lat() ) ) / (1.0 + d),
                ( points[i].lng() + ( d * points[i + 1].lng() ) ) / (1.0 + d)
            )
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please revert to me with any comments or assistance on this bug.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: We have a problem with drawing marker on Polyline which goes through the vertical meridian line (I selected the line in red).

It all works when the marker does not go over this line.

Comment: What is the problem with drawing the marker?

Comment: Marker draw in wrong side, not by polyline.

Comment: you can check [here codepen](https://codepen.io/the_tc/pen/brzqdM)

Comment: Where did you get your interpolation equation from?  It looks like that is your issue (it doesn't support inputs that cross the anti-meridian)

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how fix this

Comment: Where did you get your interpolation equation from? (second request)  I don't understand it, as I don't know where it came from.  You could attempt to use the API v3 built in interpolate function, but you would have to refactor your code to use that.

Comment: I have code with API v3 Interpolate [here](https://codepen.io/the_tc/pen/dzrdme) , but i need that marker will be by polyline.